# Why does a multicolumn foreign key allow nonexisting values

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

Consider the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
   FooId1 int NOT NULL,
   FooId2 int NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(FooId1, FooId2)
);

INSERT INTO Foo(FooId1, FooId2) VALUES (1, 10), (2, 20);

CREATE TABLE Bar
(
   BarId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   FooId1 int NULL,
   FooId2 int NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Bar ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FOO
    FOREIGN KEY(FooId1, FooId2)
    REFERENCES Foo(FooId1, FooId2);

INSERT INTO Bar(BarId) VALUES(42);
```

If I then try

```
UPDATE Bar
    SET FooId1 = 3,
        FooId2 = 30
    WHERE BarId = 42;
```

I'm getting an foreign key violation as expected. But if I do

```
UPDATE Bar
    SET FooId1 = NULL,
        FooId2 = 30
    WHERE BarId = 42;
```

it works without an error. I would have expected that even though the fields `FooId1` and `FooId2` are nullable the combination of both would always be checked against the foreign key. Why does the DB allow this `UPDATE`?

Comment: In standard SQL this could be avoided using `match full` but I don't think SQL Server supports that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a value other than NULL is entered into the column of a FOREIGN
>   KEY constraint, the value must exist in the referenced column;
>   otherwise, a foreign key violation error message is returned. To make
>   sure that all values of a composite foreign key constraint are
>   verified, specify NOT NULL on all the participating columns.
>   [Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15)

According to this explanation of the **MSDN**, you should define the **Food1** and **Food2** columns of the **Bar** columns with NOT NULL constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE Bar
(
   BarId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   FooId1 int NOT NULL,
   FooId2 int NOT NULL
)
```

So that the following insert will not work;

```
INSERT INTO Bar(BarId) VALUES(42)

Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 23
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FooId1', table 'AdventureWorks2017.dbo.Bar'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: The following also works - 

    UPDATE Bar
        SET FooId1 = 30,
            FooId2 = NULL
        WHERE BarId = 42; 

I think if you set one of the composite key columns as NULL, there is no way for the database engine to verify if the combination exists in the parent table. Hence the engine allows a NULL and non-NULL combo.

Comment: Please take into account the Bar table definition. It does not allow NULL values for the Food1 and Food2 columns otherwise you can insert NULL values to this table. UPDATE Bar SET FooId1 = 30, FooId2 = NULL WHERE BarId = 42 query does not work.

Comment: The bar table definition is allowing NULLs for FoodId1 and FooId2

CREATE TABLE Bar
(
   BarId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   FooId1 int NULL,
   FooId2 int NULL
);

Comment: "The bar table definition is allowing NULLs" so the FOREIGN key does not provide to prevent inserting or updating the NULL values because of it nature. If you use the NOT NULL constraint with FOREIGN key constraint you can avoid to insert or update NULL values. These are diffrent constraints so the update and insert rules of the FOREIGN key can change the column values to NULL values.

Comment: That's my point. Since the foreign key constraint in the Bar table does not prevent update to NULL, you can update both values or either values to NULL (I have tried this on my local sql server DB). However as in your example, you cannot set both values to non-null (3,30) because that combination does not exist in the Foo table.

Comment: Sorry @esat missed your earlier post. As per your revised Bar table definition, your comments were correct.My comments were based on the definitions provided in the original post.